# book recommendation about iterative functional equations

Tags: functional-equations

I would like to learn about **iterative functional equations**.

I read [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486445232) book, but it doesn't include such functional equations. I tried [this](https://books.google.gr/books/about/Iterative_Functional_Equations.html?id=IM7cdgtodqUC&redir_esc=y), but it was too general for my purpose. Finally I read [this](https://www.msri.org/people/staff/levy/files/MCL/Efthimiou/100914book.pdf), witch suggests [that](https://books.google.gr/books/about/On_Functions_and_Functional_Equations.html?id=eFMK8z2rt84C&redir_esc=y) book.

I tried to find a free copy of *Smital*, but I couldn't. So:

- is there a *copy of that book*?
- is there *any book like that*?
- is there *any book about iterative functional equations*?

Thanks in advance!